# Calling a function in child from parent says "not a function"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I might be misunderstanding how parent-child relations are supposed to work in React (new to it) but the following should work in my mind:

I have a parent called `<Home/>` and in it, I have a child called `<ProjectDialog>` which is a Google Material Dialog that I'm going to customize after I get this to work.

In the child I have the following code:

```
handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
};
```

Pretty normal stuff honestly. But I wanna be able to change the open state from the parent, which I attempt here:

```
let dialog = <ProjectDialog/>;

class Home extends Component {

    handleCardClick = id => {
        dialog.handleOpen();
    };
```

But when I click any of the elements that are supposed to trigger this dialogue I get the error that handleOpen() is not a function.

Is there some other way I could do this? Would it make sense to store the open state in props instead and trigger it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the way things are supposed to work.

You have to do it declaratively, meaning that the open/close information should be kept in the parent and transmitted with props to the child.

Something like this:

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    isDialogOpen: false
  }

  handleOpen = () => this.setState({ isDialogOpen: true })

  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <ProjectDialog isOpen={ this.state.isDialogOpen } />
      ...
      <button onClick={ this.handleDialogOpen }>
        Open project dialog
      </button>
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm, okay. I'll do that then. Thanks.